# Hi. I am trying to install sass loader and node sass I try this one Yarn add Sass-loader@6.0.6 node-sass@4.5.3 but it's not working thanks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass, css-float

Yarn add Sass-loader@6.0.6 node-sass@4.5.3

When I run this it show error in terminal.
What should I do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `yarn add sass-loader@6.0.6` instead of Sass-loader@6.0.6